# RTL with visual composer for wordpress

Tags: wordpress, right-to-left, visual-composer

I have problem RTL with the visual composer for WordPress, I have an empty space from the right side. at row !!
What can I do?
Please help me.

problem RTl with visual composer
[image]

Comment: It might be worth explaining your code a bit?

Answer (score 0):

try this code it will fix the direction issue

```
 body.rtl .vc_row[data-vc-full-width] {
    position: relative;
    width: 100vw !important;
    right: 50% !important;
    left: auto !important;
    transform: translateX(50%) !important;
    padding-left: calc( (100vw - 1140px) / 2 ) !important;
    padding-right: calc( (100vw - 1140px) / 2 ) !important;
}
@media(max-width:767px){
    body.rtl .vc_row[data-vc-full-width] {
        padding-left: 15px !important;
        padding-right: 15px !important;
        margin-right: 0 !important;
        margin-left: 0 !important;
    }
}
```